# Is it possible to drop IRPs in File System Filter Drivers?

Tags: filesystems, device-driver, kernel-module, wdk, minifilter

I have a couple of signatures and I want to build a File System Filter Driver
which can check all possible operations with the signatures. If a match is found than
the Filter Driver should drop the IRP packet completely.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: The word *drop* is incorrect. You should *complete* the irp what you want to drop, by IoCompleteRequest function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You're describing what just about every anti-virus package does.  You'll need to brush up on your NT-kernel mode development chops, and get familiar with [File System MiniFilters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You'll also want to start lurking on OSR NTFSD listserv.

A filter driver cannot "drop an IRP completely".  What it CAN do is complete them before lower drivers see them, or in the case of IRP_MJ_CREATE, cancel them before in a post operation callback.

Buckle up, you're in for a bumpy ride :)